# How can I `Enable All Tasks History` in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

In the task scheduler GUI it is easy to `Enable All Tasks History`

See also [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013132/how-can-i-enable-the-windows-server-task-scheduler-history-recording](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11013132/587279)

[image: Enable All Tasks History button in GUI]

How can I Enable All Tasks History through PowerShell?

I have looked at `Set-ScheduledTask` and `New-ScheduledTask`, but nothing useful there (as far as I can see).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After doing a bunch of research, I found that the History tab is just a view of a windows event log, displayed using MMC snapin. So really, all that button is doing is disabling / enabling the windows event log for the task scheduler. Here is the script to automate pushing of that button :

```
$logName = 'Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational'
$log = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogConfiguration $logName
$log.IsEnabled=$true
$log.SaveChanges()
```

Sources that got me there: 
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/automate-tasks-with-task-scheduler-from-windows-vista-inside-out 
http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/07/15/pstip-how-to-enable-event-logs-using-windows-powershell/

Answer (score 2):

From an elevated command prompt or PowerShell

`wevtutil set-log Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational /enabled:true`

Comment: Thanks. Just verified it worked on Windows Server 2019. Note that if it works there's no output but I ran Task Scheduler, disabled All Tasks History, closed it, ran this command, and reopened Task Scheduler and confirmed it was now enabled. I personally prefer this over accepted answer because it's only one line, but both are right.